# Amazon Cognito - update email programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to update the value of the standard attribute **email** of a user in a AWS Cognito user pool, but I'm getting this error:

**Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model.InvalidParameterException: user.email: Attribute cannot be updated**

The code I'm using is:

```
AdminUpdateUserAttributesRequest adminUpdateUserAttributesRequest = new()
{
UserPoolId = CognitoUserPoolId,
Username = userDetailMessage.CognitoUsername
};

var emailAttribute = new AttributeType
{
Name = "email",
Value = userDetailMessage.Email
};
adminUpdateUserAttributesRequest.UserAttributes.Add(emailAttribute);

var _ = _client.AdminUpdateUserAttributesAsync(adminUpdateUserAttributesRequest).Result;
```

The same code is working as expected uptading, for example, a custom attribute, but I cannot use it for updating email attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created UserPool you defined schema https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-schemaattribute.html

For example:

```
Schema:
        - Name: 'email'
          AttributeDataType: 'String'
          DeveloperOnlyAttribute: False
          Mutable: True
          Required: True
```

Mutable attribute  is answer to your question

You can check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-schemaattribute.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-schemaattribute-mutable

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but mutable attribute is valid only for cognito custom attribute. The email attribute is a standard cognito attribute and I cannot define it as mutable. If I undestood correctly, the standard attributes are mutable by default. I have defined email as standard attribute (and I cannot update it), and I have defined two custom attribute, that I can update without any problems. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC0dT.png)

Comment: I checked few month ago. You can create and check (

Comment: Thanks! I have re-created the pool with cloud formation script, using your suggestion, and now is working as expected. Thanks again.